# error declaring function C++ - Expected ';' at end of declaration list & Expected ')'

Tags: c++, function, function-declaration

I am attempting to define a function and running into several errors.
I am able to define one function successfully like this:

```
void simulatedFixture(int fixAddress);
```

however when I attempt to define the next function like this:

```
void addFixture(bool simShow; int x; int y; int w; int h; int universe; int address; int channelCount);
```

I encounter the following errors:

> Expected ';' at end of declaration list

> Expected ')'

> Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

I have no idea where I could be going wrong as I feel like I am doing the same thing, just with a few more parameters.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: function arguments are separated by `,` not `;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters should be separated by comma `,`, not by semicolon `;`.

See e.g. here for more details in layman terms:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functions-in-c/

https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_056.HTM

Or here for precise technical reference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function